# Julia Bio.jl walk through files simultaneously

Tags: julia

I'm using the Bio.jl ([Bio.Seq](https://github.com/BioJulia/BioSequences.jl)) for walking through files. Now I want to walk through two files simultaneously. Is there a way to achieve this similarly to the implementation like on regular files? Or any other way?

e.g.:

```
reader1 = open(FASTQ.Reader, "reads1.fastq")
reader2 = open(FASTQ.Reader, "reads2.fastq")

secondfile = readlines(reader2)

for (lines,record) in enumerate(reader1)
    seqnamefirstfile = record.name
    seqnamesecondfile = secondfile[lines].name
end
close(reader)
```

Comment: Use multithreading or multiprocessing?

Comment: thats possible, but I need to do something with the corresponding lines in both files or I would have to save them before

Answer (score 1):

Maybe using `zip`?

```
reader1 = open(FASTQ.Reader, "reads1.fastq")
reader2 = open(FASTQ.Reader, "reads2.fastq")

for (read1,read2) in zip(reader1,reader2)
    seqnamefirstfile = read1.name
    seqnamesecondfile = read2.name
end
```